# xjc or jaxb2-maven-plugin or maven: weird behavior while compiling XSDs, processing files twice but with altered names?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

Not sure where the issue is here; I suspect XJC but it's been driven by the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` within `maven`, so there's a couple of layers to unpack.

I'm compiling a folder of XSDs and it seems to be processing each file twice, once with the actual filename and once with a slightly altered filename.  [This is on OSX, by the way, but I don't think it's a straight case-sensitive filesystem problem at all (as you'll see later).]

Here's the relevant part of the `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>xjc</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The `src/main/resources` contains these XSDs:

```
ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd     ITIS_Final_3_0_0.xsd        LRMS_Final_09_07.xsd        TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd
ATIS_Partial_03_00_74.xsd   ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd   LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd   TCIP_4_0_0_Local.xsd
IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd       ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd     LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd TMDD_Partial_0_0_0.xsd
IM_Partial_03_00_38.xsd     ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd       LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd
ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd        LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd        LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd
```

when I run `maven`, it fails on very single file with something like:

```
[ERROR] file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd[35,50]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'RouteRequest' is already defined
...
[ERROR] file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ATIS_Partial_03_00_74.xsd[22,38]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: (related to above error) the first definition appears here
...
```

note that the filename in the first error doesn't even exist; it's the same as the 2nd filename (which does exist) with the first underscore-separated word transformed to lowercase (but note the second word, `Partial`, is left unchanged).

Looking at `maven -X` output, I'm pretty sure it's XJC itself that's doing this, but I haven't been able to determine yet how to fix it.

Note that this project *is* a sub-project in a larger `maven` project, but I don't think that's relevant.  For what it's worth, my `maven` command line in the parent project is: `mvn -X -U install -pl onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api`. (`onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api` is this sub-project.)

Comment: Can you add other details about your XSD? Is possible that an XSD will processed twice because some other XSD import it.

Comment: Are these public schemas? I could try to compile them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have checked your schemas.

Your original problem is due to the incorrect imports. For instance, th schema `TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd` has the following imports:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.im-partial-03-00-38" schemaLocation="im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.itis-final-3-0-0" schemaLocation="itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.lrms-final-09-07" schemaLocation="lrms_Final_09_07.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.tcip-4-0-0-local" schemaLocation="tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd"/>
```

Whereas the files are named in different case:

```
IM_Partial_03_00_38.xsd
ITIS_Final_3_0_0.xsd
LRMS_Final_09_07.xsd
TCIP_4_0_0_Local.xsd
```

This is actually incorrect as URLs are *actually* case sensitive. So I would say, import structure of these schemas is invalid.

When you compile the schemas, XJC creates and maintains a hashmap URL -> schema document which it uses to avoid loading the same schema twice. URLs (or "system ids", specificaly) are treated *case-sensitive*.

If you compile all of the schemas (`*.xsd`) then some of the schemas are included into the compilation set (at least) twice: first time directly and the second time via direct or indirect import. So you basically get `IM_Partial_03_00_38.xsd` two times. And since the XJC uses case-sensitive system ids for the schema cache, it thinks these are two different documents, tries to compile the same file twice - which leads to collisions. (The errors you get.)

If you just compile `TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd` then each schema is accessed only once. The operating system happily ignores case when accessing files and everything works.

I have experimented with your schemas in the following [demo project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-demos/tree/master/APTA-TCIP-S-01). (Schemas ZIP is downloaded during the build, so it's legally non-problematic). I had to add a bindings file, but got it to work rather fast. This works on my machine (Windows) but I think this may fail on *nix. Not sure though.

Then I thought I could use a catalog file to fix the case problem in schema URLs.

To my regret, this did not work easily.

First, I have found out that it is not practical to rewrite system ids when compiling local files. The URLs to be rewritten are given as fully-qualified absolute `file://.../schema.xsd` URLs, so including such rewriting rules in a catalog file will make the catalog file directory/machine-specific, which is not practical. This is actually a XJC catalog resolver problem, but I [will try to address it](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/19).

Next, I thought that if local file URLs don't work then absolute URLs will do. Let's *pretend* we want to compile schemas from inside the ZIP file from the original URL:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes/>
                <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The URL `http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd` does not work, of course. (Remember, we're just *pretending*.) But it gives an absolute URL which is not machine-specific.

To let XJC resolve schemas from this URL we'll need a catalog file. If we've made local copies of schemas in `src/main/resources` then the catalog file `src/main/resource/catalog.cat` *should* resolve the schemas from `http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set` to `src/main/resources`:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set/" "./"
```

I thought, *then* we could rewrite the invalid lower-case URLs and everybody's happy.

Well this worked *but only for the absolute url `http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd`*. XJC was trying to resolve relative imports just as relative URLs like `lrms_Final_09_07.xsd` instead of (as I have expected) as absolute URLs like `http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set/lrms_Final_09_07.xsd`.

For a second, when I was compiling *local* files, they *were* resolved as absolute URLs first. And when I tried to compile a schema via *absolute* URLs, relative imports were resolved as *relative* URLs.

Nevertheless at the end I have arrived to the following catalog file:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip!/Schema%20Set/" "./"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd" "TMDD_Partial_0_0_0.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "lrms_Final_09_07.xsd" "LRMS_Final_09_07.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd" "ATIS_Partial_03_00_74.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd" "IM_Partial_03_00_38.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd" "ITIS_Final_3_0_0.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd" "TCIP_4_0_0_Local.xsd"

REWRITE_SYSTEM "TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd" "TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd" "atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd" "ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd" "ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd" "LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd" "LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd" "ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "TMDD_Partial_0_0_0.xsd" "TMDD_Partial_0_0_0.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd" "ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd" "LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd" "LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd" "IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd" "ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd" "LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd"
```

Rewriting lowercase file names into uppercase was exactly what I wanted to do. But why I had to rewrite all the other file names into identicat file names is above my understanding.

Nevertheless, the catalog file above is 3 times more that it should have been, but it works. Here is [another demo project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-demos/tree/master/APTA-TCIP-S-01-catalog) which now also builds without errors.

Unfortunatelly, I have to say that catalogs still do not work satisfactory. I have filed the following issues in [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin):

- [Allow rewriting system ids for local files](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/19)
- [Allow rewriting relative import URLs with base absolute URLs as absolute URL](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/20)
- [Rewriting relative import URLs with base absolute URLs must not be mandatory](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/21)

To be clear, from my point of view **none of these issues are bugs in my `maven-jaxb2-plugin`**. This is something I "inherit" from XJC and the catalog resolver used there.

But I will try to solve it in my plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive investigation and report.  I will let folks at APTA know; they should at least fix the discrepancy in case between the `import`s and the actual filenames.

Comment: @denishaskin You're welcome. There's also a bit unconventional namespace URIs and for some reason duplication of schemas `..._for_atis` or `..._for_im` - this will lead to almost identical packages of classes (not very good for development). Apart from that these schemas are quite good.

Answer (score 0):

This can be many many things.

- First of all, check your `import`s and `include`s, the wrong name very probably comes from one of them. (Credit goes to Xstian).
- If it does, consider [using the catalog file](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Fixing_broken_references_in_schema.html) to fix it.
- Next, as the error points to two different places in a schema file, so I would also consider a possibility of an error in the schema. What do you have there? Can you show relevant schema fragments? Is it some public schema we could check.
- [This](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1045) might be a relevant issue.

Ok, how would *I* address this.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and also the author/lead dev of the [OGC Schemas project](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) which compiles a [huge set of GIS schemas](http://schemas.opengis.net/).

- I'd use my own plugin as it

  - fixes a number of XJC issues
  - outputs debug information on schema resolution
- Put all the schemas in `src/main/resources`
- Check all the `import`s and `include`s if everything correct
- In case of problems with schema locations in `import`s and `include`s, I'd write a catalog file which fixes/rewrites the invalid references
- I'd run the compilation with `mvn -X clean install` and check the log, specificaly the schema resolution part.
- In case of problems I'd either edit the catalog file, or, as the last measure patch the schemas (sometimes you really have to do this)
- For patching I'd create a separate "original" copy of schemas and apply a patch using the Maven patch plugin during the build. (Not just simply edit local copies.)

I did all of this in the mentioned [OGC Schemas Project](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas).

An example of how the schema resolution log may look like:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM: http://www.w3.org
    maven:org.hisrc.w3c:w3c-schemas:jar::!/w3c
resolveSystem(http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd)
Resolved system: http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd
    maven:org.jvnet.ogc:ogc-schemas:jar::!/ogc/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd
[DEBUG] Resolved dependency resource [Dependency {groupId=org.jvnet.ogc, artifactId=ogc-schemas, version=2.0.1-SNAPSHOT, type=jar, classifier=null, resource=ogc/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd}] to resource URL [jar:file:/C:/Repository/org/jvnet/ogc/ogc-schemas/2.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ogc-schemas-2.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ogc/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd].
```

This normally sheds some light on what's happening and which schemas get loaded.

Most of the hints are applicable to [jaxb2-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-maven-plugin) as well.

Comment: The schema is public, and can be found at http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip

Comment: @denishaskin OK, I'll try it out. Is it something many people may be interested in or more a niche thing? I.e. would an open-source project on GitHub make sense?

Comment: follow-on question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936271/xjc-maven-jaxb2-plugin-cryptic-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-javax-xml-bind

Comment: re: GitHub, well, it's a schema from a standards body, and you know how they can be... but publishing it to GitHub would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

@Xstian had the answer (although I found it before I read the comment).

I was working with a `pom.xml` that I assumed had been used successfully before, but now I don't believe that's the case.

The issue was that I needed to be compiling only the primary XSD, which was including other XSDs via `import`.  Because I was having XJC compile all of the XSDs in the folder, it was compiling some of them twice and hence the duplicate definitions.

By changing the the relevant part of the `pom.xml` to be as below, I no longer have that issue (although I have another which I will post separately):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>xjc</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaFiles>TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</schemaFiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```