# xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin: cryptic java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef.required()

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm attempting to use `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to compile the XSDs at http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip

Using this `pom.xml`, and the command line below (run from the parent folder), the compilation fails with a fairly cryptic error message (also given below):

**`pom.xml`**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>onebusaway-nyc</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.onebusaway</groupId>
    <version>2.14.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.onebusaway</groupId>
  <artifactId>onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**command line** (in the parent project folder)

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" mvn -X -U clean install -pl onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api
```

**error message**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate (default) on project onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate failed. UndeclaredThrowableException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef.required() -> [Help 1]
```

**Last part of `maven` output (long because of `-X`)**

```
[INFO] Started execution.
[INFO] JAXB API is loaded from the [jar:file:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar!].
[INFO] Detected JAXB API version [2.1].
[INFO] pluginArtifacts:[org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:maven-plugin:0.11.0:, org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-core:jar:0.11.0:compile, com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile, junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile, org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin:jar:0.11.0:compile, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11:compile, org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2:compile]
[INFO] specVersion:2.2
[INFO] encoding:UTF-8
[INFO] locale:null
[INFO] schemaLanguage:null
[INFO] schemaDirectory:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources
[INFO] schemaIncludes:[TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd]
[INFO] schemaExcludes:null
[INFO] schemas:[]
[INFO] bindingDirectory:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources
[INFO] bindingIncludes:[*.xjb]
[INFO] bindingExcludes:null
[INFO] bindings:[]
[INFO] disableDefaultExcludes:false
[INFO] catalog:null
[INFO] catalogResolver:null
[INFO] generatePackage:null
[INFO] generateDirectory:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/target/generated-sources/xjc
[INFO] readOnly:false
[INFO] extension:true
[INFO] strict:true
[INFO] writeCode:true
[INFO] verbose:true
[INFO] debug:false
[INFO] args:[]
[INFO] forceRegenerate:false
[INFO] removeOldOutput:false
[INFO] produces:[**/*.*, **/*.java, **/bgm.ser, **/jaxb.properties]
[INFO] otherDepends:null
[INFO] episodeFile:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/target/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode
[INFO] episode:true
[INFO] classpathElements:[/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/target/classes]
[INFO] plugins:null
[INFO] episodes:null
[INFO] useDependenciesAsEpisodes:false
[INFO] scanDependenciesForBindings:false
[INFO] xjcPlugins:null
[INFO] episodes:null
[INFO] schemaFiles (calculated):[/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd]
[INFO] bindingFiles (calculated):[]
[INFO] xjcPluginArtifacts (resolved):[]
[INFO] xjcPluginFiles (resolved):[]
[INFO] xjcPluginURLs (resolved):[]
[INFO] episodeArtifacts (resolved):[]
[INFO] episodeFiles (resolved):[]
Parse catalog: ./xcatalog
Loading catalog: ./xcatalog
Default BASE: file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/xcatalog
Catalog does not exist: file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/xcatalog
[INFO] optionsConfiguration:OptionsConfiguration [specVersion=2.2
 generateDirectory=/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/target/generated-sources/xjc
 generatePackage=null
 schemaLanguage=null
 schemas=[file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd]
 bindings=[]
 plugins=[]
 catalogs=[]
 catalogResolver=org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.resolver.tools.MavenCatalogResolver@1d87b360
 readOnly=false
 packageLevelAnnotations=true
 noFileHeader=false
 enableIntrospection=false
 disableXmlSecurity=true
 accessExternalSchema=all
 accessExternalDTD=all
 contentForWildcard=false
 extension=true
 strict=true
 verbose=true
 debugMode=false
 arguments=true]
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd)
Using java.util.ServiceLoader
[INFO] File [/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd] might have been changed since the last build.
[INFO] File [/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/pom.xml] might have been changed since the last build.
[INFO] Checking up-to-date depends [[/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd, /Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/pom.xml]].
[INFO] Checking up-to-date produces [[]].
[INFO] Depends timestamp [1,415,987,486,000], produces timestamp [null].
[INFO] File [/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd] might have been changed since the last build.
[INFO] File [/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/pom.xml] might have been changed since the last build.
[INFO] Checking up-to-date depends [[/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd, /Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/pom.xml]].
[INFO] Checking up-to-date produces [[]].
[INFO] Depends timestamp [1,415,987,486,000], produces timestamp [null].
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[INFO] Parsing input schema(s)...
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd)
resolveSystem(atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.atis-partial-03-00-74,atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd
resolveSystem(ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-final-3-0-0-for-atis,ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd
resolveSystem(ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-3-0-0-local-for-atis,ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd
resolveSystem(LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07-for-atis,LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd
resolveSystem(LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-local-atis,LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd
resolveSystem(ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.atis-03-00-74-local,ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd
resolveSystem(tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.tmdd-partial-00-00-00,tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd
resolveSystem(im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.im-partial-03-00-38,im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd
resolveSystem(ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-local-for-im,ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd
resolveSystem(LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07-for-im,LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd
resolveSystem(LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-local-for-im,LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd
resolveSystem(IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.im-03-00-38-local,IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd
resolveSystem(itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-final-3-0-0,itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd
resolveSystem(ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-3-0-0-local,ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd
resolveSystem(lrms_Final_09_07.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07,lrms_Final_09_07.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: lrms_Final_09_07.xsd
resolveSystem(LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.dummy-local-address,LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd
resolveSystem(tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.tcip-4-0-0-local,tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd)
Failed to create InputSource: tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/TCIP_4_0_0_Final.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.atis-partial-03-00-74,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.atis-partial-03-00-74,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/atis_Partial_03_00_74.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-final-3-0-0-for-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-final-3-0-0-for-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Final_3_0_0_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-3-0-0-local-for-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-3-0-0-local-for-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07-for-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07-for-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-local-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-local-atis,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_atis.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.atis-03-00-74-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.atis-03-00-74-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ATIS_03_00_74_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.tmdd-partial-00-00-00,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.tmdd-partial-00-00-00,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tmdd_Partial_0_0_0.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.im-partial-03-00-38,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.im-partial-03-00-38,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/im_Partial_03_00_38.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-local-for-im,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-local-for-im,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07-for-im,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07-for-im,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Final_09_07_for_im.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-local-for-im,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-local-for-im,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_Local_for_im.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.im-03-00-38-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.im-03-00-38-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/IM_03_00_38_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-final-3-0-0,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-final-3-0-0,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/itis_Final_3_0_0.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-3-0-0-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.itis-3-0-0-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/ITIS_3_0_0_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/lrms_Final_09_07.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/lrms_Final_09_07.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/lrms_Final_09_07.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.lrms-final-09-07,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/lrms_Final_09_07.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.dummy-local-address,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.dummy-local-address,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/LRMS_09_07_Local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.tcip-4-0-0-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd)
resolveSystem(file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd)
resolvePublic(http://www.tcip-4-0-0-local,file:/Users/dhaskin/clients/cs/onebusaway-nyc/onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api/src/main/resources/tcip_4_0_0_local.xsd)
[INFO] Compiling input schema(s)...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:28.839s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 14 09:57:04 PST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/403M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate (default) on project onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate failed. UndeclaredThrowableException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef.required() -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate (default) on project onebusaway-nyc-tcip-api: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.11.0:generate failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.required(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.AbstractField.annotateReference(AbstractField.java:202)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.AbstractField.annotate(AbstractField.java:161)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.AbstractListField.generate(AbstractListField.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.UntypedListField.<init>(UntypedListField.java:112)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.UntypedListFieldRenderer.generate(UntypedListFieldRenderer.java:77)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.field.DefaultFieldRenderer.generate(DefaultFieldRenderer.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateFieldDecl(BeanGenerator.java:777)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassBody(BeanGenerator.java:558)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:261)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:169)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:288)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.generateCode(XJC22Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:326)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef.required()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1973)
    at com.sun.codemodel.TypedAnnotationWriter.invoke(TypedAnnotationWriter.java:112)
    ... 38 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

**start of mvn -x**

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 08:22:22-0700)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven31/3.1.1/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Note the XSD I am trying to compile can be found at http://www.aptatcip.com/APTA-TCIP-S-01%204.0_files/Schema%20Set.zip (although when I use the XSDs there "out of the box", XJC compilation seems to hang).

Comment: It probably does not hang, it probably downloads schemas which are included via absolute URLs. Try to plug out of the network ans see what happens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could you post your `java -version` or the beginning of the `mvn -X` log?

The problem is most probably here:

```
[INFO] Detected JAXB API version [2.1].
...
[INFO] specVersion:2.2
```

- You'll probably need to update your JDK or
- put `jaxb-api-2.2.jar` into your $JRE_HOME/lib/endorsed directory.
- Alternatively you can put the JAXB API jar into a different folder and include it into the `java.endorsed.dirs` system property.

I see you're using [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) now. If you want to stay on JAXB 2.1 with your JDK (which is probably somewhat outdated), you can:

- configure `<specVersion>2.1</specVersion>`
- or use the plugin artifact id `maven-jaxb21-plugin`, it is a variant of the plugin which is linked with JAXB 2.1.

Comment: Added mvn -X output.  Yes, looks like I should upgrade my java to 1.7.

Comment: @denishaskin Aha. See [this table](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html). Or you can do the endorsed trick. Or use `maven-jaxb21-plugin`. I'll [add a warning on API oncompatibility](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/17) in the next version.

Comment: I had the same problem, solved downgrading xjc to 2.1.x

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my JDK to the correct version (1.7, in this case) addressed this.

Comment: I believe you are still using JDK's version if you upgraded to 1.7 (JAXB 2.2.*). That's fine, however, if you still wish to use the specific JAXB API, ss @lexicore indicated, use `<specVersion>` in Maven, or set `<sysproperty key="java.endorsed.dirs" value="${endorsed.dir}" />` inside of your Ant script's `<java>` task, depending on your build management tool, and place `jaxb-api-2.2.*.jar` in `${endoresed.dir}` folder.